# How to make template function work for char[32] and string type?

Tags: c++, templates, stl

i want to design a template function, which build a shared memory with size = sizeof(T) * n

it returns template type pointer. and i pass a default value as default value.

function def looks like:

```
#ifndef SHMHELP_HPP_                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
#define SHMHELP_HPP_
          
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
        
namespace cppbox {
  namespace shm {
    enum EmShmOpenMode:int {
      MODE_CREATE,
      MODE_RD,
    };

    template<typename T>  //, T v>
    T* func(const char* filename, size_t n, int rdflag, T v) {  // mode: 0666
      int offlag = rdflag == EmShmOpenMode::MODE_CREATE ? O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_RDWR :  offlag = O_RDWR;
      int shm_fd = shm_open(filename, offlag, 0666);
      if (-1 == shm_fd)  {
        if (rdflag != EmShmOpenMode::MODE_CREATE) {
          std::cerr << "shm_open open failed: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
          return nullptr;
        }
        offlag = O_RDWR| O_TRUNC;
        if (-1 == (shm_fd = shm_open(filename, offlag, 0666))) {
          std::cerr << "shm_open create failed: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
          return nullptr;
        }
      }

      if (rdflag == EmShmOpenMode::MODE_CREATE) {
        if (ftruncate(shm_fd, n*sizeof(T))) {
          std::cerr << "ftruncate failed: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
          close(shm_fd);
          return nullptr;
        }
      }

      T* ret = (T*)mmap(0, n*sizeof(T), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);
      close(shm_fd);
      if (ret == MAP_FAILED) {
        std::cerr << "mmap failed: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        return nullptr;
      }

      if (rdflag == EmShmOpenMode::MODE_CREATE) std::fill((T*)ret, ((T*)ret) + n, v);
      return ret;
    }
  }
};
#endif  // SHMHELP_HPP_
```

it's ok when i call `func<int>("a", 100, 0, 0)` or `func<double>("a", 100, 0, 0.)`

but it crashed when i call `func<std::string>("a", 100, 0, "")`

```
int main() {
  std::string*p = cppbox::shm::MapShm<std::string>("b", 100, cppbox::shm::MODE_CREATE, "huang");
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    cout << (*p)[i] << " ";
  }
}
```

and complier will reject to complie when i call `func<char[32]>("a", 100, 0, "")` like this:

```
int main() {
    char[32]*p = cppbox::shm::MapShm<char[32]>("b", 100, cppbox::shm::MODE_CREATE, "huang");  // compiler will reject in this line
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
      cout << (*p)[i] << " ";        
    }//*/
  }
```

how can i make `func<char[32]>("a",100, 0, "")` and `func<std::string>("a", 100, 0, "")` work?

Comment: Please be more specific than "it seems not work".

Comment: This looks strangely familiar to another question that was deleted a few minutes ago, where the general concensus via crystal ball was that you're trying to assign arrays.  And yes, it looks like you are (via `std::fill`).  You can't.  What you _can_ do is create a simple wrapper like `struct cstring32 { char s[32]; };` and use that.

Comment: Storing non-trivial types like `std::string` in shared memory will inevitably lead to undefined behaviour.

Comment: This code is problematic `T* ret = (T*)mmap(0, n*sizeof(T), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);` because you are allocating space for strings, but failing to construct the strings (no string constructor is called here). If you really want to do this you need to investigate a technique called *placement new*. That technique will allow you to construct objects in the memory you have allocated.

Comment: Or, you could use `std::uninitialized_fill` instead of `std::fill`. Remember you are dealing with raw memory here, `std::fill` is not correct.

Comment: @john i am curious about how std::vector<std::string> work, maybe i should read more.

Comment: @xyhuang It uses placement new (or it's equivalent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
if (rdflag == EmShmOpenMode::MODE_CREATE) std::fill((T*)ret, ((T*)ret) + n, v);
```

to

```
if (rdflag == EmShmOpenMode::MODE_CREATE) std::uninitialized_fill((T*)ret, ((T*)ret) + n, v);
```

That should help with the `std::string` case.

`std::fill` can only be used on memory that already contains objects. In your case you have uninitialised (raw) memory containing no constructed objects, so `std::uninitialized_fill` should be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it is not a safe practice to allocate memory inside a function and return its pointer. Because one may forget to free the memory!

Second since there is no way to assign a default value for arrays and the desired default value is somewhat empty anyway, you could do it by having 2 function overloads, one for assigning a default value and another for just allocating memory like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <type_traits>


//general purpose type that can be constructed from any type!
class all{
public:
    template<typename T>
    all(T){}
};

//First overload
template <typename T>
T* pre_func(size_t n, T defaultvalue) {
  T *pointer = (T*) calloc(n, sizeof(T));
  for(size_t counter = n; counter--;){
      pointer[counter] = defaultvalue;
  }
  return pointer;
}

//second overload
template <typename T>
T* pre_func(size_t n) {
  T *pointer = (T*) calloc(n, sizeof(T));
  return pointer;
}

//overload selector
template <typename T>
T* func(size_t n, typename std::conditional<std::is_array<T>::value, all, T>::type defaultvalue){
    if constexpr(std::is_array<T>::value){
        return pre_func<T>(n);
    }else{
        return pre_func<T>(n, defaultvalue);
    }
}
```

then in your program call the function overloads any way you want for normal types and array types like:

```
    func<int>(100, 0);
    func<char[32]>(100, "");
```

Comment: ok, thanks for your help, i think you switched from the previous closed questions. i should apologize for the previous bad description. thanks again

Comment: @xyhuang I updated my answer to be more closer to what you want. Now you do not need to call the function differently! Please take a look!